# ValueError: row index was 31, not allowed by .xls format

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I can run it as a python script,but it's wrong after used pyinstaller.
Anyone knows,Thanks!

```
Errorlog shows:
  File "test_func.py", line 130, in merged
    self.worksheet.write_merge(j[0], j[1], idx, idx, value)
  File "site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1114, in write_merge
  File "site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1088, in write
  File "site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1142, in row
  File "site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 37, in __init__
ValueError: row index was 31, not allowed by .xls format
```

Answer (score 0):

It's well after I annatotation source code which raised ValueError

```
xlwt Row.py
    # if not (isinstance(rowx, int_types) and 0 <= rowx <= 65535):
          # raise ValueError("row index was %r, not allowed by .xls format" % rowx)
```